# deploying from sql server express to datacenter

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I'm taking the database that I created with SQL server express and putting it on a server in a datacenter. There are 2 database files in AppData folder: the aspnetdb.mdf file and the file I created for my site MySite.mdf. I'm using the ASP login control and that works with the ASPNETDB.mdf file and it's working. If I log in without the correct username/pwd, it'll display a bad login message.

However, as soon as I login and the site goes to make a request to MySite.mdf, I get an error "Invalid object name 'dbo.Users'." which is the name of the first table the site looks into after the login.

I've attached the MySite.mdf file to the server and copied the connection string the hosting company is generating into the web.config file and left the rest as is.

Could it be that I can't attach a sql express file?

Please let me know if you've run into this issue or if you have any suggestions.

Thanks.

Comment: Your issue seems a little confusing the way you've described it. Do you have direct access to the sql server? Have you attached your aspnetdb file? If so, how? You say you've attached MySite.mdf but you can't access it... how did you attach it? You mention a "hosting company" but if you're talking about shared hosting, then it seems unlikely that you'd have sufficient access to the database server to upload and attach an mdf file.

Comment: I'm using discountasp.net hosting. In the SQL manager, there's an Attach database functionality and once you go through this functionality, you're issued a connection string.

Comment: What happens when you use their sql manager to browse your database.  Do you see that table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description and the following assumptions:

- your authentication still works
- you haven't mentioned attaching your aspnet.mdf
- you have separate databases for security and datastore
- you're probably still testing locally

I'd guess that your application is still pointing at your local aspnet database - that's why authentication still works. Typically in a shared host, you'll have to install/insert the asp.net security database items to your main database. See [This MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x28wfk74.aspx) for instructions on setting up the asp.net database objects.

You need to establish whether or not you've actually attached your database or not. Is there an online "database manager" you can access? Or can you connect to your database from SSMS or your dev environment and run a simple query?